# when trying run my flutter project get some error

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Redmi Note 8 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
I/flutter ( 5876): The user wants to login with mi and 123

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0
      > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.pom'.
               > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/216.58.208.142, dl.google.com/2a00:1450:4002:805:0:0:0:200e] failed: Network is unreachable (connect failed)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 34s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file

Comment: open android folder and check proper error and also check build.gradle file.